# QGIS to ArcGIS Feature Class

Tags: arcgis-desktop, qgis-3

I have data in QGIS I have to get it into ArcGIS (ArcMap) (ESRI's) GeoDB as a feature class, I have tried 2 routes but I can't find a route through.

Route 1.

I've exported from QGIS to GeoJSON, ArcMap can import this with the correct extension, but I can't convert the GeoJSON to a feature class.

Route 2.

I export to shapefile, the column names are truncated to 13 characters. I import as a feature class, now I need to rename the columns. I've tried the below, but it won't let me rename the column headers.

Any ideas how to get around these issues?

I'd rather not have to rename the columns at all.

`Right-click the table or feature class and click Properties. Click the Fields tab. Choose the field you want to modify from the Field Name list. To rename the field, click the text of the name and type a new name.`

Comment: I'm confused: the title of your post states QGIS, but your question says that you "have to use ArcGIS".  So, what software are you using? Regarding the shapefile column names, they are limited to 10 characters, so consider yourself lucky if you're getting 13!  Note that you can create *alias* names for your columns that are longer than 10/13. In the attribute table view, right-click the column name and go to *Properties*, where you can edit a new alias name.

Comment: What is your question?  You seem to be asking two unmarked questions.

Comment: @StuSmith amended for clarity

Comment: @PolyGeo the question as stated: Any ideas how to get around these issues - I'd rather not have to rename the columns at all.

Comment: I think it would help if you could place a single question mark in your question body to indicate your question.  What is the relevance of the last paragraph in backticks?

Comment: It's the answer you get if you google it, I put it there to avoid getting that answer to demonstrate I had actually tried doing something before asking. I usually use PostGIS but this is for an external client and things have to be just so.

Comment: When you say that you “have data in QGIS” do you mean that you are displaying PostGIS data as a layer in QGIS or something else?

Comment: Please edit your question to include exactly what format your data in QGIS is.

Comment: Why not use Geopackage? https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/databases/connect-sqlite.htm

Comment: the data was a shp file, but in QGIS I refactored it with >13 column names, that's why I said `in QGIS`

Comment: @Mapperz would love to, but I have to follow the clients requirements.

Comment: Are you saying that you added a shapefile to QGIS to create a layer and created aliases with longer names on the fields of that layer?

Comment: I added a shp to QGIS, used the refactor tool to create a scratch layer renaming columns longer than the 10 character limit.

Comment: Please edit your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

In the geoprocessing toolbox should be 'JSON to Feature Class'. It should take a GeoJSON and turn it into a feature class in a FGDB. This should allow you to use it as a native layer in ArcMap.

https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/json-to-features.htm

---

The reason you probably cannot rename the columns from the shapefile is that the underlying file is still a shapefile.  ArcMap will not let you to name it beyond the specification in dBase. Convert it first into a layer in a FGDB with 'Feature Class to Feature Class' in the geoprocessing toolbox.  You should be able to rename the columns beyond the 13 characters.

https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/feature-class-to-feature-class.htm

Comment: JSON to Feature Class fails for GeoJSON, I renamed the .geojson to .json, wouldn't parse.

Comment: Feature Class to Feature Class also failed

Comment: Hmm, I am at a bit of a loss. I double checked it with a dataset of my own to be sure it worked. I am using latest of both version of software. Are there any errors?

Comment: 10.5.1 maintained through my work. Error parsing json file. feature class to feature class Error cannot create output.